# Is there a way to get the first line from all HDFS files in a directory?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, filesystems, hdfs, distributed-computing

I am trying to get the first line from all HDFS files in my cluster's "/user" directory.

Currently we have a Hive table that contains information about these files such as owner, complete path (location), owner's corporate ID, date of file creation, file read/write permissions, etc. I want to add a new column to this Hive table which contains the complete first line of the file.

That's why I'm looking for a way to extract first line of all HDFS files in a directory (in my case, the "/user" directory). Can I achieve this using Spark maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a recursive search for all the files and then use `cat` and take the first line as specified in the other answer by @gsamaras

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/ | grep -v "^d" | awk '{print $8}' | while read file; do
    echo "${file}"
    hdfs dfs -cat ${file} | head -1
    echo
done
```

`grep` is used with `v` flag to invert all the rows starting with `d` i.e. directories

`awk` is used to print the 8th field in each row which is the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/* | head
```

and play around.

[cat](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html) works like/is for concatenate.

[head](http://www.linfo.org/head.html) reads the first few lines of any text given to it as an input and writes them to standard output (which, by default, is the display screen)

Comment: That's a useful command for getting the info from the immediate files within the directory. The problem is, /user by itself does not contain files, it contains several other directories and these directories contain other directories/files. Basically it is like a web of directories and files inside /user and I was wondering if I can get the info for all files within this "web".